# mongoDB select from collection with relation

Tags: mongodb, select, collections

I need to select users for corresponding data from query.

I have  this collection in my DB (two or more rows are output of my query as well)

```
> db.Friends.find()
{ "userId" : "k3XCWdN5M2pbzBiFD", "followeeId" : "3MTmHcJNEzaaS8hrd","_id" :  "aiRD.." }
{ "userId" : "k3XCWdN5M2pbzBiFD", "followeeId" : "SoTozuZ4nWooRBeFz","_id" :  "QingX.."    }
```

When it would be just one result as findOne(...) the second query would looks like this:

```
users.findOne({ _id: firstQueryResult.followeeId })
```

But now the problem is... how can i select the users from users collection when i dont have only one followeeId but more of them?

Please someone show me an example of code.

**My research: 
Is this a good solution?**

```
friendsData.forEach(function(relationShip) {
    followeeIds.push(relationShip.followeeId);
});
console.log(followeeIds);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i finalllly figure out the problem.For next readers:

1. Check if autopublish is enabled or disabled.
2. If is disabled you need to publish the collection from the DB

   ```
   Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
       return Meteor.users.find({},
                      {fields: {'username': 1}});
   });
   ```

   PS: i want to publish only username field and thats all!
3. You need to subscribe the data as well!

   ```
   Meteor.subscribe("userData");
   ```
4. Now you can access other users data this way:

   ```
   users= Meteor.users.findOne({username: "Nolifer"});
   ```
5. To my original problem ... i will probably use this function for iterate over more then one row result(its more a SQL term but i am not sure what term use in mongoDb maybe a document? whatever):

   ```
   users.forEach(function(user) {
       console.log(user);
   });
   ```

Thats it!

P.S.: I think there is nothing wrong on this but what i know right? :) So if someone know a better way please leave a comment. If not give me know if it was useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the mongo manual, use the `$in` operand: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/#op._S_in

```
db.inventory.find( { qty: { $in: [ 5, 15 ] } } )
```

Comment: Because it returns: ["3MTmHcJNEzaaS8hrd", "SoTozuZ4nWooRBeFz"] but i still can't do your code: db.inventory.find( { qty: { $in: followeeIds } } ).count() it returns 0

Comment: Ok i think the problem will be somewhere else... its because i can't access users collection from server side. Its made by accounts-ui package but i dont know how to enable publishing the collection hm...